# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 using libsqlite3.dylib with FMDB Xcode 7 ios9

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, fmdb, xcode7-beta2

I am using Xcode 7 and iOS 9 to create a simple app which saves the data and retrieves it using sqllite3. However I am getting the following error message while Building the app using libsqlite3.dylib library and FMDB retrieved from github.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_sqlite3_bind_blob", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_int", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_int64", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_null", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_parameter_count", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase executeQuery:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:error:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_parameter_index", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase executeQuery:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:error:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_busy_handler", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase setMaxBusyRetryTimeInterval:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_changes", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase changes] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase close] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_column_blob", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet dataForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet dataNoCopyForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_column_bytes", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet dataForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet dataNoCopyForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_column_count", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet columnCount] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet columnNameToIndexMap] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet kvcMagic:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet resultDictionary] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:
```

I am driving myself crazy after searching around however could not find any solution. Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Check whether if libsqlite3.dylib is added in the Link Binary with Libraries section in Build Phases

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering! I have the same setup under build phases. Even I tried adding both sqlite3 files. Still have the same issue though

Comment: @RegisSt-Gelais I'm having the same problem in Xcode 7, except I have `libsqlite3.tbd` added in the list already.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like your project is linking against libsqlite3.  Double check that it's linking against it, and if it is, maybe add it as a linker flag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how do I add the item as linker flag ? I am new to iOS development not sure yet